# How to parse Square response nested key values in Ruby 2.2.10

Tags: ruby, string, hash, square

How would you get the value of the last_4 key form this hash?

I have a response nonce from a Square transaction.  I pass the response through Ajax to Ruby where it comes out as a parameter string.  Iv'e tried converting the string to a hash.  I've also tried JSON.parse.

This is an actual response nonce from a Square sandbox transaction.  I've truncated some of the IDs and replaced others.  Also i put in carriage returns to make it more human readable:

```
{:transaction=>{
    :id=>"smqfzS00qbp1lOy...", 
    :location_id=>"CBASE...", 
    :created_at=>"2019-02-19T19:45:18Z", 
    :tenders=>[{
        :id=>"34670bfa-9d09-406a-910c-9c3e8ab82321", 
        :location_id=>"CBASE...", 
        :transaction_id=>"smqfzS00qbp1lOy...", 
        :created_at=>"2019-02-19T19:45:18Z", 
        :note=>"Online Transaction", 
        :amount_money=>{
            :amount=>65000, 
            :currency=>"USD"
            }, 
        :type=>"CARD", 
        :card_details=>{
                :status=>"CAPTURED", 
                :card=>{
                    :card_brand=>"VISA", 
                    :last_4=>"9999", 
                    :fingerprint=>"22737c9b012a..."
                    }, 
        :entry_method=>"KEYED"
        }
    }], 
    :product=>"EXTERNAL_API"
    }
}
```

I have it as a string from an ajax call and convert it to a hash or parse it:

```
sqresp = Hash.new(square_resp) # this works
sqresp = JSON.parse(square_resp) # this fails
```

I've tried pulling out just the id, which is the first nested key:

```
sqresp[:transaction] # this works but I get the whole string
```

But if I go any deeper it fails:

```
sqresp[:transaction][:id] # this fails
sqresp[:transaction[:id]] # kinda makes sense but fails
sqresp[:transaction][:tenders][:amount_money][:card_details][:card][:last_4] # of course this fails too,it's just a deeper scrape.
```

It would be great to have a Ruby method for breaking out all the Square key/values but with an example of how to pull out last_4, I can do the rest.

Thanks.

Comment: Your first sentence is misleading because what follows is not a hash, but, as you go on to explain, is a string. You might be better off showing your return value from the Square Transaction ("nounce"?) or from Ajax. (I know nothing about either.) If you do that, more tags would be called for.

Comment: If `str` is your string (I treated it as the body of a heredoc), `h = eval(str)` (or `instance_eval(str)`) produces the hash, after which `h[:transaction][:tenders].first[:card_details][:card][:last_4] #=> "9999"`. `Hash.new(str)` merely creates an empty hash with `str` as its default value.

Comment: RE: You might be better off showing your return value from the Square Transaction ("nounce"?) or from Ajax. 

nonce is the term for the response that comes from Square: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/sqpaymentform/setup?q=card-nonce#step-6-set-the-form-action-parameter

Square returns the nonce as a string that they populate into the value of a hidden input field.  I passed that field value to Ruby through a JSON string in an AJAX call.  I pasted the actual string - exception I added carriage returns to emphasize the structure.  The tags are appropriate for search purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Cary, that worked!

```
sqresp = instance_eval(square_resp)
sqresp[:transaction][:tenders].first[:card_details][:card][:last_4]
```

Thanks!
There's no option to vote for your comment.