# How to get a table of records from Square's transaction hash?

Tags: javascript, json, ruby, square

I need to iterate through this hash of Square transactions and join each record to the results of a MySQL query.  Is there a way to get the records in the Square transactions hash into an array that is more like a table?

I posted a similar question a few weeks ago ([How to parse Square response nested key values in Ruby 2.2.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55365027/how-to-parse-square-response-nested-key-values-in-ruby-2-2-10/55365773#55365773)) where the hash had only one record but now I need to iterate through all the Transactions.  Notice that the hash can also contain Refund transactions, which I would want to parse out separately.  And some transactions will be missing the reference_id field.

```
{:transactions=>[
{:id=>"sacfx8eqLYsBQom7G9kV7gS1K4lbnMG83w3U0Gpzu1cCJROfZvRJqLhO", 
:location_id=>"CBASEJJZMYbNZW8F1bbRjRuPQ7Q", 
:created_at=>"2019-04-10T16:38:57Z", 
:tenders=>[{
    :id=>"eeb92f2a-379b-55c6-439b-f0f5c44925c8", 
    :location_id=>"CBASEJJZMYbNZW8F1bbRjRuPQ7Q", 
    :transaction_id=>"sacfx8eqLYsBQom7G9kV7gS1K4lbnMG83w3U0Gpzu1cCJROfZvRJqLhO", 
    :created_at=>"2019-04-10T16:38:57Z", 
    :note=>"Online Transaction", 
    :amount_money=>{:amount=>65000, :currency=>"USD"}, 
    :processing_fee_money=>{:amount=>1915, :currency=>"USD"}, 
    :type=>"CARD", 
    :card_details=>{:status=>"CAPTURED", 
                    :card=>{:card_brand=>"VISA", 
                            :last_4=>"1111", 
                            :fingerprint=>"50b16672bf4472e9058524e3c0a060faab196bc3e43f9c693a870c7e8b6da626"
                            }, 
                    :entry_method=>"KEYED"
                    }
}], 
:reference_id=>"796", 
:product=>"EXTERNAL_API"
}, 

{:id=>"mvMhdOrfBdXQvE0S6EPFoeHf7Fm8duSJgsk4bZyt6APQTa2PGkix6LhO", 
:location_id=>"CBASEJJZMYbNZW8F1bbRjRuPQ7Q", 
:created_at=>"2019-04-10T01:22:16Z", 
:tenders=>[{
    :id=>"693c42d4-5e16-52a3-5594-5e8dd4ff9f95", 
    :location_id=>"CBASEJJZMYbNZW8F1bbRjRuPQ7Q", 
    :transaction_id=>"mvMhdOrfBdXQvE0S6EPFoeHf7Fm8duSJgsk4bZyt6APQTa2PGkix6LhO", 
    :created_at=>"2019-04-10T01:22:16Z", 
    :note=>"Online Transaction", 
    :amount_money=>{:amount=>65000, :currency=>"USD"}, 
    :processing_fee_money=>{:amount=>1915, :currency=>"USD"}, 
    :type=>"CARD", 
    :card_details=>{:status=>"CAPTURED", 
                    :card=>{:card_brand=>"VISA", 
                        :last_4=>"1111", 
                        :fingerprint=>"50b16672bf4472e9058524e3c0a060faab196bc3e43f9c693a870c7e8b6da626"
                        }, 
                    :entry_method=>"KEYED"
                    }
}], 
:product=>"EXTERNAL_API"
},
...
],
:refunds=>[... refunds here ...]
}
```

I put in the carriage returns to make it easier to see the key/values.
Additionally, Square's sample in their documentation (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/?q=reference_id#endpoint-transactions-listtransactions) shows keys in quotation marks but the actual response that comes to Ruby is just as I showed it above, where all the keys are just colon key name - like :id

Comment: Are you doing anything to the response once you get it from Square? Square always returns a JSON body as the response. For example `response = Unirest.get "https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations", headers:{"Authorization" => "Bearer access_token", "Accept" => "application/json" }` and then doing response.body returns a JSON string so you can just do something like `response.body["locations"]` to get the JSON array of locations.

Comment: And so assuming you have a JSON response, you can simply do something like `transactions = response.body["transactions"]` and loop through it like `for transaction in transactions` and do whatever you want inside the loop.